# How to exit vim after change command on movement

Tags: vim, neovim

Let's say I change a word with `cw`. That leaves me in insert mode.
I find it counter intuitive that if I move to a different line, I'm still in insert mode.
I would like to exit insert mode without pressing `ESC`, for example when I move to different line with arrow keys.

How could I do this?

Comment: You find still being in insert mode because you didn't leave insert mode "counterintuitive"?

Comment: This is what `c` (change command) does, removing some text and leaving you in insert mode. If you just want to delete some text, use `d` instead (you are still in normal mode).

Answer (score 1):

You can remap the arrow keys to automatically leave insert mode:

```
inoremap <Up>    <Esc><Up>
inoremap <Right> <Esc><Right>
inoremap <Down>  <Esc><Down>
inoremap <Left>  <Esc><Left>
```

You may also want to remap `<PageDown>` and `<PageUp>`, `<ScrollWheelDown>`, and `<ScrollWheelDown>` if you use those.

---

One downside of this is that it may not work well with some plugins. That is, the plugin will work fine, but it may move the cursor without leaving insert mode as you expect it to. Plus, if you get used to this you may find using a Vim without these mappings (on a server, or someone else's computer) to be frustrating.